# Start google course builder from Ubuntu command line

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu

I followed [these](https://www.google.com/edu/openonline/course-builder/docs/1.10/set-up-course-builder/deploy-your-app.html) instructions to install Google CourseBuilder. Used Ubuntu via vagrant on a vm. I want to access my course site on my host windows pc since my ubuntu does not have a GUI. To do this it recommended I use the --noauth flag.
It asks for a verification code - where do I get this? See command I ran below:
[image]

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly, and retract any sensitive info accordingly: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2295256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice it says:

> Go to the following link in your browser:
>
> ```
> https://accounts.google.com....
> ```

You have to open that link in your browser(by copying and pasting or by clicking). This will present the Google Account Chooser dialog where you select the Google Account you want to deploy the course builder app with... At the end of the flow you'll be presented with a code which you then copy and paste back in your shell and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Yes thanks. Have trouble to copy that link from a PuTTy command line to get it to my host. Any tips?

Comment: Not familiar with PuTTy, but does this help? https://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/putty/putty-how-to-copy-and-paste-to-and-from-a-putty-window/

Comment: definitely does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced some trouble with installation. For anyone having trouble installing Course Builder from any operating system (Windows, Linux, Mac, etc.), I made a guide and video which details how to do so:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfNQle_ZxLc

The full text guide is in the YouTube video's description.